# Gitlab CI Include is not including

Tags: gitlab-ci

I don't get it. I have two repos. One for infrastructure, and the other for project code. Inside project code, I have .gitlab-ci.yml file that will include one job for creating env variables, another include file that will include other stages inside the job. Every other stage is triggered, but the first include is not triggered no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

Project gitlab-ci

```
# Stages
stages:
  - pre-build test
  - build
  - post-build test
  - deploy
  - environment
  - e2e

# Main Variables
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: normal
  IMAGE_VERSION: "latest"
  CARGO_HOME: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cargo
  FF_USE_FASTZIP: "true"
  ARTIFACT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fast"
  CACHE_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fastest"
  STAGING_BRANCH: "master"
  VARIABLES_FILE: variables.txt

# Include main CI files from infrastructure repository
include:
  - project: 'project/repo-one'
    ref: master
    file: '/gitlab-ci/env/ci-app-env.yml'
  - project: 'project/repo-one'
    ref: master
    file: '/gitlab-ci/app/ci-merge-request.yml'
```

env ci file

```
env mr:
  stage: .pre
  before_script:
    - TEST_VAR="TEST"
    - IMAGE_PATH="/var/www"
  script: 
    - echo "export TEST_VAR=$TEST_VAR" > $VARIABLES_FILE
    - echo "export IMAGE_PATH=$IMAGE_PATH" > $VARIABLES_FILE
    - cat $VARIABLES_FILE
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $VARIABLES_FILE
```

Comment: Are you saying that the job `env mr` does not appear in any pipeline at all? Are you by chance using `rules:` or pipelines for merge requests in other jobs? Or just branch pipelines?